# Is there a way to disable "Open in [App Name]" suggestion when you tap the link on chrome?

Tags: android, app-store, applinks, custom-url

Every link that is related to our domain, opens a popup that suggest opening the app. We recently tried to get rid of it but we couldn't manage to do it. I am not very experienced in this topic.

Excuse my ignorance. I assume it is related to something that we did in our app development.

> Open with: [App Name] or Chrome ---- Just this once or Always

Sometimes it repeats the same question even if we select "Always" option for the Chrome. It becomes annoying really really quick :)

Is there anyone who know what might be the issue or how to disable that functionality or how to target specific pages on our website ?

---

Edit: It seems that the correct way to define that functionality is "disambiguation dialog".

Edit 2: My goal is to disable disambiguation dialog. I don't want my users to be directed to the app. Or even asked whether they want to open it in app. I want those links to directly move users to the webpage rather than asking whether he/she wants to open it in application.

Answer (score 2):

By passing the disambiguation dialog is only possible with the Android 6.0 API for [App Linking](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#app-linking)

Per the [Handling App Links training](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html):

> Android 6.0 (API level 23) and higher allow an app to designate itself
>   as the default handler of a given type of link. If the user doesn't
>   want the app to be the default handler, they can override this
>   behavior from Settings.
>
> Automatic handling of links requires the cooperation of app developers
>   and website owners. A developer must configure their app to declare
>   associations with one or more websites, and to request that the system
>   verify those associations. A website owner must, in turn, provide that
>   verification by publishing a Digital Asset Links file.

This involves creating the appropriate intent handler and enabling automatic verification by adding `android:autoVerify="true"`:

```
 <activity ...>

  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.android.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.android.com" />
  </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Then, updates must be made on the website side by [declaring a website association](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#web-assoc), which ensures that the website owner and the app developer both coordinate to allow the app to automatically become the default for a URL scheme.

Further more study this [Handling Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html)

Study this if you wish that most of the URLs opens directly to specific content in your Android app. Android App Links can drive more traffic to your app, help you discover which app content is used most, and make it easier for users to share and find content in an installed app. Follow and implement suggested link for minimizing this behavior of dialogue opening on clicking URL

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ghulam. Just to make it sure. I will ask once more. Are you saying that there is no possible way to disable that dialog? We don't want to direct users to the app.

Comment: you may consult to that website owner end  which coordinate to allow the app to automatically opens and  become the default for a specific URL scheme.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html

Study this if you wish that most of the URLs directly to specific content in your Android app. Android App Links can drive more traffic to your app, help you discover which app content is used most, and make it easier for users to share and find content in an installed app.
Follow and implement suggested link for minimizing this behavior of dialogue opening on clicking URL